# Error 404 not found after running docker-compose with SpringBoot and MongoDB

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

My DockerFile is:

```
    FROM openjdk:8
VOLUME /tmp
ADD target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
#RUN bash -c 'touch /app.jar' 
#EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Dspring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://mongo/players","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

And the docker-compose is:

```
  version: "3"
services:
    spring-docker:
        build: .
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
        depends_on:
            - db
    db:
        image: mongo
        volumes:
            - ./data:/data/db
        ports:
            - "27000:27017"
        restart: always
```

I have docker Image and when I use docker-compose up, anything goes well without any error.
But in the Postman, when I use GET method with localhost:8080/player I do not have any out put, so I used the IP of docker-machine such as 192.168.99.101:8080, but I have error 404 Not found in the Postman.
what is my mistake?!

The docker-compose logs:

```
   $ docker-compose logs
Attaching to thesismongoproject_spring-docker_1, thesismongoproject_db_1
spring-docker_1  |
spring-docker_1  |   .   ____          _            __ _ _
spring-docker_1  |  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
spring-docker_1  | ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
spring-docker_1  |  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
spring-docker_1  |   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
spring-docker_1  |  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
spring-docker_1  |  :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.6.RELEASE)
spring-docker_1  |
spring-docker_1  | 2020-05-31 11:36:39.598  INFO 1 --- [           main] thesisM
ongoProject.Application           : Starting Application v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT on e81c
cff8ba0e with PID 1 (/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by root in /)
spring-docker_1  | 2020-05-31 11:36:39.620  INFO 1 --- [           main] thesisM
ongoProject.Application           : No active profile set, falling back to defau
lt profiles: default
spring-docker_1  | 2020-05-31 11:36:41.971  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.
c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data MongoDB repositori
es in DEFAULT mode.
spring-docker_1  | 2020-05-31 11:36:42.216  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.
c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in
225ms. Found 4 MongoDB repository interfaces.
spring-docker_1  | 2020-05-31 11:36:44.319  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w
.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)

spring-docker_1  | 2020-05-31 11:36:44.381  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apach
e.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
spring-docker_1  | 2020-05-31 11:36:44.381  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.apa
che.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.
33]
spring-docker_1  | 2020-05-31 11:36:44.619  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.c
.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationC
ontext
spring-docker_1  | 2020-05-31 11:36:44.619  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.web
.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization c
ompleted in 4810 ms
spring-docker_1  | 2020-05-31 11:36:46.183  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.mon
godb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[db:270
17], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms'
, maxWaitQueueSize=500}
spring-docker_1  | 2020-05-31 11:36:46.781  INFO 1 --- [null'}-db:27017] org.mon
godb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1
, serverValue:1}] to db:27017
spring-docker_1  | 2020-05-31 11:36:46.802  INFO 1 --- [null'}-db:27017] org.mon
godb.driver.cluster               : Monitor thread successfully connected to ser
ver with description ServerDescription{address=db:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=
CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[4, 2, 7]}, minWireVersion
=0, maxWireVersion=8, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30,
 roundTripTimeNanos=5468915}
spring-docker_1  | 2020-05-31 11:36:48.829  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.s.c
oncurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTas
kExecutor'
spring-docker_1  | 2020-05-31 11:36:49.546  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w
.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with
context path ''
spring-docker_1  | 2020-05-31 11:36:49.581  INFO 1 --- [           main] thesisM
ongoProject.Application           : Started Application in 11.264 seconds (JVM r
unning for 13.615)
spring-docker_1  | 2020-05-31 11:40:10.290  INFO 1 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.s.c
oncurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTa
skExecutor'
db_1             | 2020-05-31T11:36:35.623+0000 I  CONTROL  [main] Automatically
 disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none
'
db_1             | 2020-05-31T11:36:35.639+0000 W  ASIO     [main] No TransportL
ayer configured during NetworkInterface startup
db_1             | 2020-05-31T11:36:35.645+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] Mong
oDB starting : pid=1 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=1a0e5bc0c503
db_1             | 2020-05-31T11:36:35.646+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] db v
ersion v4.2.7
db_1             | 2020-05-31T11:36:35.646+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] git
version: 51d9fe12b5d19720e72dcd7db0f2f17dd9a19212
db_1             | 2020-05-31T11:36:35.646+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] Open
SSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
db_1             | 2020-05-31T11:36:35.646+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] allo
cator: tcmalloc
db_1             | 2020-05-31T11:36:35.646+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] modu
les: none
db_1             | 2020-05-31T11:36:35.647+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] buil
d environment:
db_1             | 2020-05-31T11:36:35.647+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]
distmod: ubuntu1804
db_1             | 2020-05-31T11:36:35.647+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]
distarch: x86_64
db_1             | 2020-05-31T11:36:35.647+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]
target_arch: x86_64
db_1             | 2020-05-31T11:36:35.648+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] opti
ons: { net: { bindIp: "*" } }
db_1             | 2020-05-31T11:36:35.649+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Dete
cted data files in /data/db created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setti
ng the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
db_1             | 2020-05-31T11:36:35.650+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] wire
dtiger_open config: create,cache_size=256M,cache_overflow=(file_max=0M),session_
max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(f
ast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager
=(close_idle_time=100000,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=250),statis
tics_log=(wait=0),verbose=[recovery_progress,checkpoint_progress],
db_1             | 2020-05-31T11:36:37.046+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Wire
dTiger message [1590924997:46670][1:0x7f393f9a0b00], txn-recover: Recovering log
 9 through 10
db_1             | 2020-05-31T11:36:37.231+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Wire
dTiger message [1590924997:231423][1:0x7f393f9a0b00], txn-recover: Recovering lo
g 10 through 10
db_1             | 2020-05-31T11:36:37.294+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Wire
dTiger message [1590924997:294858][1:0x7f393f9a0b00], txn-recover: Main recovery
 loop: starting at 9/6016 to 10/256
db_1             | 2020-05-31T11:36:37.447+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Wire
dTiger message [1590924997:447346][1:0x7f393f9a0b00], txn-recover: Recovering lo
g 9 through 10
db_1             | 2020-05-31T11:36:37.564+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Wire
dTiger message [1590924997:564841][1:0x7f393f9a0b00], txn-recover: Recovering lo
g 10 through 10
db_1             | 2020-05-31T11:36:37.645+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Wire
dTiger message [1590924997:645216][1:0x7f393f9a0b00], txn-recover: Set global re
covery timestamp: (0, 0)
db_1             | 2020-05-31T11:36:37.681+0000 I  RECOVERY [initandlisten] Wire
dTiger recoveryTimestamp. Ts: Timestamp(0, 0)
db_1             | 2020-05-31T11:36:37.703+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Time
stamp monitor starting
db_1             | 2020-05-31T11:36:37.704+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]
db_1             | 2020-05-31T11:36:37.704+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** W
ARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
db_1             | 2020-05-31T11:36:37.704+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] **
        Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
db_1             | 2020-05-31T11:36:37.705+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]
db_1             | 2020-05-31T11:36:37.712+0000 I  SHARDING [initandlisten] Mark
ing collection local.system.replset as collection version: <unsharded>
db_1             | 2020-05-31T11:36:37.722+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Flow
 Control is enabled on this deployment.
db_1             | 2020-05-31T11:36:37.722+0000 I  SHARDING [initandlisten] Mark
ing collection admin.system.roles as collection version: <unsharded>
db_1             | 2020-05-31T11:36:37.724+0000 I  SHARDING [initandlisten] Mark
ing collection admin.system.version as collection version: <unsharded>
db_1             | 2020-05-31T11:36:37.726+0000 I  SHARDING [initandlisten] Mark
ing collection local.startup_log as collection version: <unsharded>
db_1             | 2020-05-31T11:36:37.729+0000 I  FTDC     [initandlisten] Init
ializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/data/db/diagnostic.d
ata'
db_1             | 2020-05-31T11:36:37.740+0000 I  SHARDING [LogicalSessionCache
Refresh] Marking collection config.system.sessions as collection version: <unsha
rded>
db_1             | 2020-05-31T11:36:37.748+0000 I  SHARDING [LogicalSessionCache
Reap] Marking collection config.transactions as collection version: <unsharded>
db_1             | 2020-05-31T11:36:37.748+0000 I  NETWORK  [listener] Listening
 on /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
db_1             | 2020-05-31T11:36:37.748+0000 I  NETWORK  [listener] Listening
 on 0.0.0.0
db_1             | 2020-05-31T11:36:37.749+0000 I  NETWORK  [listener] waiting f
or connections on port 27017
db_1             | 2020-05-31T11:36:38.001+0000 I  SHARDING [ftdc] Marking colle
ction local.oplog.rs as collection version: <unsharded>
db_1             | 2020-05-31T11:36:46.536+0000 I  NETWORK  [listener] connectio
n accepted from 172.19.0.3:40656 #1 (1 connection now open)
db_1             | 2020-05-31T11:36:46.653+0000 I  NETWORK  [conn1] received cli
ent metadata from 172.19.0.3:40656 conn1: { driver: { name: "mongo-java-driver|l
egacy", version: "3.11.2" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Linux", architecture: "
amd64", version: "4.14.154-boot2docker" }, platform: "Java/Oracle Corporation/1.
8.0_252-b09" }
db_1             | 2020-05-31T11:40:10.302+0000 I  NETWORK  [conn1] end connecti
on 172.19.0.3:40656 (0 connections now open)
db_1             | 2020-05-31T11:40:10.523+0000 I  CONTROL  [signalProcessingThr
ead] got signal 15 (Terminated), will terminate after current cmd ends
db_1             | 2020-05-31T11:40:10.730+0000 I  NETWORK  [signalProcessingThr
ead] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
db_1             | 2020-05-31T11:40:10.731+0000 I  NETWORK  [listener] removing
socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
db_1             | 2020-05-31T11:40:10.731+0000 I  -        [signalProcessingThr
ead] Stopping further Flow Control ticket acquisitions.
db_1             | 2020-05-31T11:40:10.796+0000 I  CONTROL  [signalProcessingThr
ead] Shutting down free monitoring
db_1             | 2020-05-31T11:40:10.800+0000 I  FTDC     [signalProcessingThr
ead] Shutting down full-time diagnostic data capture
db_1             | 2020-05-31T11:40:10.803+0000 I  STORAGE  [signalProcessingThr
ead] Deregistering all the collections
db_1             | 2020-05-31T11:40:10.811+0000 I  STORAGE  [signalProcessingThr
ead] Timestamp monitor shutting down
db_1             | 2020-05-31T11:40:10.828+0000 I  STORAGE  [TimestampMonitor] T
imestamp monitor is stopping due to: interrupted at shutdown
db_1             | 2020-05-31T11:40:10.828+0000 I  STORAGE  [signalProcessingThr
ead] WiredTigerKVEngine shutting down
db_1             | 2020-05-31T11:40:10.829+0000 I  STORAGE  [signalProcessingThr
ead] Shutting down session sweeper thread
db_1             | 2020-05-31T11:40:10.829+0000 I  STORAGE  [signalProcessingThr
ead] Finished shutting down session sweeper thread
db_1             | 2020-05-31T11:40:10.829+0000 I  STORAGE  [signalProcessingThr
ead] Shutting down journal flusher thread
db_1             | 2020-05-31T11:40:10.916+0000 I  STORAGE  [signalProcessingThr
ead] Finished shutting down journal flusher thread
db_1             | 2020-05-31T11:40:10.917+0000 I  STORAGE  [signalProcessingThr
ead] Shutting down checkpoint thread
db_1             | 2020-05-31T11:40:10.917+0000 I  STORAGE  [signalProcessingThr
ead] Finished shutting down checkpoint thread
db_1             | 2020-05-31T11:40:10.935+0000 I  STORAGE  [signalProcessingThr
ead] shutdown: removing fs lock...
db_1             | 2020-05-31T11:40:10.942+0000 I  CONTROL  [signalProcessingThr
ead] now exiting
db_1             | 2020-05-31T11:40:10.943+0000 I  CONTROL  [signalProcessingThr
ead] shutting down with code:0
```

Comment: Can you add `docker-compose up` logs over here ?

Comment: you mean: docker-compose logs?

Comment: Yes, when you start the containers, can you add the logs

Comment: the problem is, I am beginner for Docker and I do not know how can I add the result of this command here

Comment: Go to edit for the question, and add the logs

Comment: From a non-docker prespective, ensure that your JAVA application is set to listen on `0.0.0.0` and not `127.0.0.1`, this will ensure you can connect to the java application from any host and not just the container on which the application is running.

Comment: it listen on 127.0.0.1, but could you tell me now what i must do

Comment: Make the java app to listen on host 0.0.0.0 and also expose the port 8080 in the dockerfile and try

Answer (score 0):

for solving this problem I must put @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={MongoAutoConfiguration.class}) annotation